# Can I display different parts of singular view based on the URL?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

For simplicity's sake, imagine I have a view that contains an ul and 4 divs

```
<ul>
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
<ul>

<div class='1'></div>

<div class='2'></div>

<div class='3'></div>

<div class='4'></div>
```

Is it possible to make it so that depending on the URL, the user sees one of the four divs only? For example:

On URL www.example.com/first the user receives a view containing:

```
<ul>
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
<ul>

<div class='1'></div>
```

On URL www.example.com/second the user receives a view containing:

```
<ul>
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
<ul>

<div class='2'></div>
```

On URL www.example.com/third the user receives a view containing:

```
<ul>
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
<ul>

<div class='3'></div>
```

I could easily do that if I have 4 different views, but my goal is to have all the code in 1 view and then based on the URL to present the correct section.

Comment: Kind of unrelated to your question, but it is also possible with javascript and the HTML5 history API see HTML on this page https://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/#tabs1-js (note a page refresh takes you to same content)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check that using the request object, and checking the current segment.

For example:

```
@if(request()->is('first'))
    <div class="1"></div>
@elseif(request()->is('second'))
    <div class="2"></div>
@endif
```

This should give you the idea.

Comment: Would that work if first, second, third are the slug of /admin/{slug?} like this: Route::get('/admin/{slug?}', 'pagesController@admin')->name('admin');

Comment: it would, but you've got to know the slug name and use it as it is, not really useful if the slug is dynamic, and it could get messy pretty quick. Then it will be better to use view for each page.

Answer (score 0):

4 different views will be good idea, each view can have different html, if you use blade if else html code will be messy. make 1 master blade add your ul code in there

master.blade.php

```
<ul>
    <li>Section 1</li>
    <li>Section 2</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
    <li>Section 3</li>
<ul>
 @yeild('content')
```

extend your each view with this master layout.

first.blade.php

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class='1'></div>
@endsection
```

and so on

if all request are going to same controller method than call them like this

```
return view($slug);
```

this the beauty of laravel blade templates

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
@if(last(request()->segments()) == 'first')
    <div class='1'></div>
@endif
@if(last(request()->segments()) == 'second')
    <div class='2'></div>
@endif
```